# Twython update_status_with_media error

Tags: python, twitter, twython

I have the following code:

```
photo = open(os.path.join("images", localFileName), 'rb')
tweetThis = "status"
twitter.update_status_with_media(status=tweetThis, media=photo)
```

Here is the traceback:

```
    twitter.update_status_with_media(status=status, media=photo)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/twython/endpoints.py", line 107, in update_status_with_media
    return self.post('statuses/update_with_media', params=params)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/twython/api.py", line 234, in post
    return self.request(endpoint, 'POST', params=params, version=version)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/twython/api.py", line 224, in request
    content = self._request(url, method=method, params=params, api_call=url)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/twython/api.py", line 194, in _request
    retry_after=response.headers.get('retry-after'))
twython.exceptions.TwythonError: Twitter API returned a 403 (Forbidden), Status creation failed: Tweet creation failed.
```

I have tested `twitter.update_status(status='TEST')` which works correctly meaning I have the correct credentials and permissions. What's wrong with the media version?

Answer (score 1):

Try changing `os.path.join("images", localFileName)` to just `/path/to/file`. Not completely sure, but this is the only likely thing that is going wrong. Also, don't set your variable for your status to be `status`, it shadows the `twython` syntax: `twython.twitter.update_status_with_media(status, media)`

Here is an example:

```
from twython import Twython
from time import strftime

CONSUMER_KEY = '***'
CONSUMER_SECRET = '***'
ACCESS_KEY = '***'
ACCESS_SECRET = '***'

#load your twitter credentials
twyapi = Twython(CONSUMER_KEY,CONSUMER_SECRET,ACCESS_KEY,ACCESS_SECRET)
photo = open('/Users/aj8uppal/Desktop/images.jpg', 'rb')
twyapi.update_status_with_media(status='I love python!', media=photo)
```

Comment: No luck, I changed the status variable though.

Comment: What OS and python version are you using? Also, what is the path to the file? For example, my home directory is `/Users/aj8uppal`, and my Desktop would be in `/Users/aj8uppal/Desktop`.

Comment: Mac OS X, Python 2.7.5. I tried both relative path and absolute path.

Comment: Found the issue, was a problem with file limit size. Must be less than 3MB.

Comment: Glad you fixed it, sorry I couldn't be of help!